# Transform List<List<String>> into List<Integer> with Guava's Function

Tags: java, guava

How can I transform one List of Lists string values (`List<List<String>>`)  bellow into one list of Integer (`List<Integer>`) using Guava's Function?

```
List<String> list1 = ImmutableList.of("1", "2");
List<String> list2 = ImmutableList.of("3", "4");
List<String> list3 = ImmutableList.of("5", "6");
List<List<String>> lists = ImmutableList.of(list1, list2, list3);
```

This what I would do instead of use foreach:

```
`List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (List<String> list : lists) {
   for (String string : list) {
    Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(string);
    ints.add(integer);
    }
 }`
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the traditional for-each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public final class StringToIntegerAdapter implements Function<String, Integer> {

    public static final StringToIntegerAdapter INSTANCE = new StringToIntegerAdapter();

    /** Private constructor forces everyone to use the singleton. */
    private StringToIntegerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Integer apply(@Nullable final String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return Integer.valueOf(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can transform your String list into an Integer list in one line:

```
List<String> stringList = getMyStrings();
List<Integer> intList = Lists.transform(stringList, StringToIntegerAdapter.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Paul - regarding your question "why not a traditional for/each" - adapters like this can be handy once you have built up a suite of them for your most common needs.  As shown in my example above, transforming a whole collection only takes one concise line, instead of multiple lines for the for-each.

Comment: That's a good start, but `Iterators.transform` expects (and returns) an `Iterator`, not a `List`. Also, your code transforms a `List<String>` into a `List<Integer>`, but the OP wanted to transform a `List<List<String>>` (a list of lists) to a `List<Integer>` (a single concatenated list).

Comment: `Iterables.transform` rather than `Iterators.transform`.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the eagle eyes.  I'll tweak the answer.  Huge thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Jim's StringToIntegerAdapter, you can perform the desired transformation compactly using the following methods in Guava:

```
List<List<String>> strings = getString();
List<Integer> intList = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(
    Iterables.concat(strings), StringToIntegerAdapter.INSTANCE);
```